# Mocha --watch creating new mongoose connections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm exporting my `app.js` so that I can make integration tests with `supertest` like `request(app).get('/').expect(200)`. However, for every mocha run (through the `--watch` flag), new connection is created (I have already 28 of them).

I goes without saying that, as almost every tutorial, I'm connecting to `mongodb` inside `app.js`.

I'm not sure if this is a mocha problem, or if this can be solved using dependency inversion (I don't think so, though).

I already run mocha 5.0.0 with `--exit` flag.

How can I prevent this?

**Edit**: adding code.

It's the basic for an `app.js`

```
// app.js
const app = express();
mongoose.connect(config.mongoUri);
...
modules.exports = app;
```

Comment: Post some code so we can help you!

Comment: Edited for code, but it's the basic express structure

Comment: and if you run your tests over and over without watch, does the same thing happen?

Comment: Nope, without watch, the server completely dies. Seems like I'm missing some explicitly called close() for mongoose or similar.

Comment: I've never called close, but then I never use mocha watch. Btw where do you see the extra connections, on the mongo side?

Comment: On the terminal. I start mongo by running `mongod`, and leave it there. Logs show new connections on every test re-run.

Comment: I'll check it out on one of my projects.  Don't they just close eventually on their own?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the afterEach / beforeEach loops to manage the connection/disconnection to the DB.

Here is an example, if it is not enough I'll send you a more straightforward code:

```
  let server
  beforeEach(() => {
    server = require('../../../index')
  })
  afterEach(async () => {
    await server.close()
  })
```

**server** here is a reference to the mongoose conexion:

```
const server = app.listen(port, () => winston.info(`App listening on port ${port}`))
module.exports = server
```